# How can I modify text inside single quotes?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I have a file that contains these lines:

```
war {
    baseName = 'myApp'
    version = '1.0.2'
}
```

And a variable like:

```
variable=b123
```

I want to edit the file appending $variable value to the version number so result will be:

```
war {
    baseName = 'myApp'
    version = '1.0.2_b123'
}
```

How achieve this goal with a `bash` script?

Comment: bash isn't a text editor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would a simple `sed` do?

```
$ var=_b123
$ sed -Ee "/version/s/'(.*)'/'\1$var'/" file 
war {
    baseName = 'myApp'
    version = '1.0.2_b123'
}
```

(`/version/` checks if the line contains that string, if it does we `s`ubstitute a string inside single quotes with the same string (`(...)` captures, `\1` restores) plus the text in the variable. The quoting is not an issue here since everything we need is safe within double-quotes.)

Answer (score 0):

If you like vim, this works:

```
vim +/version +"norm 2f'i_b123" +x file
```

This opens the file and executes three commands:

- go to first line that contains "version"
- enter normal mode, go to the second `'`, go to insert mode, insert `_b123`
- write and quit